# Explode Unknown amount of variables

Tags: php

I have a string of data which is an unknown length eg `$myvar = "data,data";` and i want to `explode` the string eg `list($a, $b) = explode(",", $myvar)` which works great if I know the length of the data, but im not sure how to handle variable lengths.

i was thinking of using `if` statments.

eg: `$letter_count = substr_count($myvar, ',');`

```
if($letter_count == 2) { list($a, $b) = explode(",", $myvar) }
elseif($letter_count == 3) { list($a, $b, $c) = explode(",", $myvar) }
```

but this is not practical, anyone got any ideas how else i could do this?

Comment: why do you need to to work that way? Can't you just use the array like this? `$var = explode(",",$myvar); echo $var[0];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `explode`, it will return an array that is split by your delimiter. You would then call each item by its index position. The following example uses a space as the delimiter.

```
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
```

Answer (score 3):

just explode into a regular array reference:

```
$return = explode("," $myvar);
```

The format you're using is for...well...when you know what the expected output is.